# Can I make the LiveData static?

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I don't know if this is a stupid question. This may defeat the purpose of LiveData/ViewModel.

Can I make the LiveData static? My reason is I have a listener from a Service which updates the information. So I need to have a way from a service to "set/change" the LiveData.

**I used to do following and it works:**
1. Service changes the DB 
2. ViewModel listens to the DB change
3. UI updates from the liveData change

**I found this way is too slow. To increase the performance, I want something like:**
1. Service changes the class object directly 
2. ViewModel listens to the the class object changes
3. UI updates from the liveData change

In order to achieve what I want, either I need to make the MutableLiveData static or make the ViewModel class to share the same instance of ViewModel between Activities.

Is this good idea?

```
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

    // Note: this MutableLiveData is static
    private static MutableLiveData<MyModel> mutableLiveData;

    public MyViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    LiveData<MyModel> getLiveDataList() {
        if (mutableLiveData == null) {
            mutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
            loadDataFromDb();
        }
        return mutableLiveData;
    }

    private void loadDataFromDb() {
        // load data from DB
        // mutableLiveData.setValue(MyModelFromDb); // Omit the real implementation
    }

    // Note: this method is static
    public static void setData(MyModel newData) {
        mutableLiveData.setValue(newData);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCleared() {
        super.onCleared();
    }
}
```

Comment: "I found this way is too slow" What's "too slow"? Where is the database?

Comment: Have you looked into sending a local broadcast from your Service to a registered BroadcastReceiver in your activity and compared that update time with LiveData updates?

Comment: yes you can make it static if you think it would be faster process....but please do update the db from the same or another service.. ( **cause static data will live till the app is in foreground...if you restart the data will be lost** )

Comment: but please do update the db from the same -> yes I am planning to do that. Thank you.

Comment: A similar, but more flexible approach, is to introduce a repository layer that can cache data for you: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide#connecting_viewmodel_and_the_repository

When the repository is created, it can load data once, then watch the db for subsequent changes.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of `ViewModel` from Android Jetpack (as opposed to other versions) is for the `ViewModel` to be lifecycle aware and perform magic like destroying itself when observer is destroyed (activity/fragment), or surviving configuration changes (for example, orientation) without initialising itself all over again thereby making it much easier to deal with issues related to configuration changes.

So if you made the `ViewModel` or `LiveData` static you would actually beat their purpose and most likely leak `ViewModel`'s data, though the need to do this is understandable. So this requires you to engineer your way around it, and the first way you mentioned is probably the best way you can do it. I don't understand why you have an issue with the first solution. The way I see it, it provides the best user experience:

1. You init `ViewModel` in your fragment or activity in `onCreate` and add an `Observer` to the data.
2. If database already has some data, your observer will receive it instantly and UI will be updated with existing data instantly.
3. Service makes the API request and changes the DB
4. DB changes triggers an update to the data in `ViewModel`
5. Observer refreshes received data and you pass this to your views/adapters
6. UI updates with latest data with some nice animations that indicate addition/removal of items.

From what I can see it cant get better than this. Since your question is from months ago, I am curious to know what you ended up doing?

Comment: I don't think I get what the problem is with LiveData specifically? LiveData objects doesn't depend on viewmodels, or anything for that matter. Livedata observers only depends on the passed context to manage its own lifecycle. Making it static shouldn't cause any leaks, right?

Answer (score 0):

- I think if `MyViewModel` will have lots of `LiveData` fields it will grow with large amount of getters and setters. And what even worst, as for me, you will break the testablity of your code, because if you will create a new instance of `MyViewModel` you will expect that your `LiveData` objects are stateless at this point of time, but as it's a static object you don't know in what exactly state it is after simple creation.
- As well static methods can't be overriden. And about fields: if you will want to have common field, suppose errorMessage, in class A and class B while both of them extend class C(which contains your common field) you can have unexpected behavior. On the other hand you can duplicate this code in other classes(what is bad).
- The memory issue: if a large number of static variables/methods are used. Because they will not be GC until program ends.

But it just my opinion.